# Check if a string is an html font in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I am making a robotic "talk and respond" console, and I want to be able to change the font in the console. I know how to change the font, but I do not want to change the font if the given font is not an actual HTML font.

Example: The user enters `Arial`, the command goes through. The user enters `I lost my mommy`, the command does not go through and the computer alerts the user that the command is invalid.

I obviously do not want to create a very large array containing all of the HTML fonts. That would not make sense.

If a jQuery solution works, then let me know. I am using jQuery in my code.

Comment: What You thought of with the Array, that is actually the only Idea I can think of. Check out this [JSON Array of all Google Fonts](https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyBwIX97bVWr3-6AIUvGkcNnmFgirefZ6Sw) which should basically cover all your needs.

Comment: take a look at fontSpy library ...might help https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/jQuery-FontSpy.js

Comment: luca kiebels suggestion may be combined with a bloom filter to reduce loading time drastically...

Answer (score 1):

[JavaScript/CSS Font Detector](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/) is a library that might help.

Include the library and call

```
detective.detect('[font name]'));
```

It isn't true font identification, but it may work for what you are trying to accomplish.

`detect` returns a boolean value based on if the string value provided matches a font that is available in the browser.

```
 function isFont(fontName) {
      return fontName ? detective.detect(fontName) : false;
 }
```

Comment: This is good, but could you give me an example? I read the guide and it's a bit vague.